# VS Code task.json passing long object file list leads to g++ crash

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++

I have a project that has 1100 classes, so the g++ (using Makefile) will generate over 1100 object files (*.o). This project can link with g++ without any problem using Makefile. But when it comes to using VS code, something happens: I want to set breakpoints in the main.cpp using VScode, so also need to link to those *.o files as references. but since the number is huge, when I pass the absolute path of these *.o file to g++, it simply crashes and exit, no error message was reported.

because I am using the VS code, the task.json has one item that looks like this

```
"args": [
            "-g",
            "-std=c++17",
            "-m32",
            "${file}",
            "/obsolutePath/obj0001.o",
            "/obsolutePath/obj0002.o",
            "/obsolutePath/obj0003.o",
            "/obsolutePath/obj0004.o",

            "....",
            "/obsolutePath/obj1098.o",
            "/obsolutePath/obj1099.o",
            "/obsolutePath/obj1100.o",
            "other args"]
```

My guess is these arguments are too long which leads g++ to crash. So I move the test code to the folder where all those object files locate. but VS code says it can not file these files. That means when VS code invokes the g++, it starts at a different location. I am wondering if there is any parameter I can set so the g++ will search those object files in a specified folder, so I do not have to pass long path names to it.

Thanks

Comment: use a build Tool for this, Make, CMake, put all the OBJ files in a lib and link the lib, even Unix shell line will not be big enough

Comment: @rioV8 thanks very much, that solves my problem. I run a command like "ar ruv libTest.a *.o" to include all *.o files into a library,  only see a few undefined reference errors, which I fixed by passing those related OBJ files(which I think are already in that library), not a perfect solution, but I guess that another issue, I will need to look into a bit more detail.

Comment: you need to watch the order of obj files you put in the library, the linker only goes through the lib once, make sure the dependent obj files are put later in the library